# html form to google sheets

Tags: html, forms, google-sheets

I have html code form written on a page in Google Apps Script. The form enters data into Google Sheets and uploads images to the Google Drive folder. I want to edit the codes so that I can transfer the html code from Google Apps Script to Google Sites.
this is google apps script code

```
const rootFolderId = 'folder Id';  // Change your folder Id !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

/** The function returns an HTML service HtmlOutput object **/
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate()
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

/** Create folder in google drive **/
function createFolder(folderName) {
  try {
    const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootFolderId);
    const folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    let folder;
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
    }
    return {
      'folderId' : folder.getId()
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      'error' : e.toString()
    }
  }
}




/** upload file to google drive **/
function uploadFile(base64Data, fileName, folderId) {
  try {
    const splitBase = base64Data.split(','), type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0]
        .replace('data:', '');
    const byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    const bobFile = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    bobFile.setName(fileName);

    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    const files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    let file
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      // delete existing files with the same name.
      file = files.next()
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }
    file = folder.createFile(bobFile)
    file_Name = file.getName()
    file_Url = file.getUrl()
    return {
      'file_Name' : file_Name,
      'file_Url' : file_Url
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      'error' : e.toString()
    };
  }
}

function recordData(sData){
  const datenow = new Date()
  sData.splice(0, 0, datenow)
  const sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1")
        sht.appendRow(sData)
}
```

and this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>ss </title>
    <style>
     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    

         <form id="uploadForm" action="#">
         
         
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <select class="floating-select" id= "ssss" name="ssss" onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" required>
         
<option value=""></option>

        </select>
    <label><b>ssss</label></b>


      <div class="input-data">
        <select class="floating-select" id="aaaa" name="aaaa" onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" >
            <option value=""> </option>
           
            
        </select>
    
    <label><b>aaaa</label></b>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="input-data">
          <select class="floating-select" id= "cccc" name="cccc" onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" required>
           
  <option value=""></option>
  
 
          </select>
      <label><b>cccc</label></b>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-data">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
  <div class="underline"></div>
  <label for=""><b>name</label></b>
 </div>
 


      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="input-data">
          <input type="date"  name="date" id="date" required data-type="date" required>
          <div class="underline"></div>
          <label for=""><b><i class="fa fa-calendar-check"></i> date</label></b>
          <div class="datepicker">

        <div class="input-data">
          <div class="radio-tile-group">
           <div class="underline"></div>
           <label1><b>sex</label1></b>   
            <div class="input-container">              
              <input id="male"  value="male" type="radio" name="sex">
              <div class="radio-tile">
                <ion-icon name="man"></ion-icon>
                <label for="male">طلاب</label>
              </div>

            </div>
              <div class="input-container">
              <input id="female"  value="female" type="radio" name="sex">
              <div class="radio-tile">
                
                <ion-icon name="woman"></ion-icon>
                <label for="female">female</label>
              </div>
            

<div class="input-data">
          <input type="file" class="" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple>
        
          <div id="preview"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
          function previewImages() {
            var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
      
            if (this.files) {
              [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
            }
      
            function readAndPreview(file) {
              // File type validator based on the extension 
              if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                return alert(file.name + " no pic");
              }
              
              var reader = new FileReader();
              
              reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var imageContainer = document.createElement('div');
                imageContainer.classList.add('image-container');
      
                var image = new Image();
                image.title = file.name;
                image.src = this.result;
                imageContainer.appendChild(image);
      
                var sizeDisplay = document.createElement('p');
                sizeDisplay.classList.add('image-size');
                sizeDisplay.textContent = 'Size: ' + (file.size / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
                imageContainer.appendChild(sizeDisplay);
      
                preview.appendChild(imageContainer);
              });
              
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
          }
      
          document.querySelector('#myfile').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
        </script>

<div class="form-row">
               <div class="input-data textarea">
                 <textarea rows="10" cols="90" id="note" required></textarea>
                 <br />
                 <div class="underline"></div>
                 <label for="">note </label>
                
                </div>
               
<div class="submit">
  <input type="submit" id="sub" value="send" onclick="uploadFiles()">
  <sup id="msg"></sup>
</div>

      </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>

      const maxfile = 5 ;
      let numUploadsdone = 0;
      let numUploadstotal = 0;
      let folderName = '';
      let allFiles;
      let sData = [];

      /** save data to sheet **/
      function uploadFiles() {
        event.preventDefault();
        const folderName = document.getElementById('name').value;
        const allFiles = document.getElementById('myfile').files;
        numUploadsdone = 0;
        numUploadstotal = allFiles.length;
        sData = [];

       
          if (maxfile < numUploadstotal) {
            alert("Upload no more than " + maxfile + " files.");
          } else {
            sData.push(folderName);
            
            sData.push(document.getElementById('ssss').value);
           
            sData.push(document.getElementById('aaaa').value); 
            
            sData.push(document.getElementById('cccc').value);
            sData.push(document.querySelector('input[name="date"]').value);
            sData.push(document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked')?.value || '');
            sData.push(document.getElementById('note').value);

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createFolder_withSuccessHandler).createFolder(folderName);
          }

        function createFolder_withSuccessHandler(data){
          for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {           
            uploadFile(allFiles[i], data.folderId);
          }
        }

        function uploadFile(file, folderId) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            const content = reader.result;
            document.querySelector("#sub").value = "eeeeeee " + "(" + numUploadstotal + ")" +'  ppppppp ....';          
            
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onFileUploaded).uploadFile(content, file.name, folderId);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function onFileUploaded(r) {


          let form = document.querySelector("uploadForm");
                   
          numUploadsdone++;
          sData.push(r.file_Url);
          
          if (numUploadsdone == numUploadstotal) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().recordData(sData);
           
            numUploadsdone = 0;
          
            
          }
           document.querySelector("#sub").value = "wwwwwww" + "(" + numUploadstotal + ")" + '   tttttttt';  
           document.getElementById('uploadForm').reset();
            allFiles = [];
            sData = [];
        }
      }



    </script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  
  
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope to find your solution
Thank you

I have html code form written on a page in Google Apps Script. The form enters data into Google Sheets and uploads images to the Google Drive folder. I want to edit the codes so that I can transfer the html code from Google Apps Script to Google Sites.
this is google apps script code